# moduleId should be a string in "Ng2SliderComponent"

Tags: javascript, angular

my angularcli.json is

```
 "scripts": [
         "../node_modules/ng2-slider-component/ng2-slider.component.js",
        "../node_modules/ng2-slideable-directive/slideable.directive.js",
        "../node_modules/ng2-styled-directive/ng2-styled.directive.js"
      ],
```

its also in package.json.

my app.module.ts is like below.i imported all the component here.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Ng2SliderComponent } from 'ng2-slider-component/ng2-slider.component';
import { SlideAbleDirective } from 'ng2-slideable-directive/slideable.directive';
import { Ng2StyledDirective } from 'ng2-styled-directive/ng2-styled.directive';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SlideAbleDirective,
        Ng2StyledDirective,
        Ng2SliderComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

But it is showing the error like below.please give me some solution.i am using angular cli.what to do.any idea.thanks in advance.please give the solution very fastly,i am stucking by these for a long tym. thanks in advance.ok

Comment: You mention an error, what is the error? The whole error, please.

Comment: compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: moduleId should be a string in "Ng2SliderComponent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the line 404 (approximately) in `ng2-slider.component.js` to:

`moduleId: module.id + "",` fixes the problem.

Source:  [Github issue link](https://github.com/Bogdan1975/ng2-slider-component/issues/28#issuecomment-286365882)

Comment: fixed.new one has come.Ng2SliderComponent.html:28 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of undefined
    at Ng2StyledDirective

Comment: any solution for this

Comment: @pranavyoyo hmm I don't know about that but EmersonJair's suggestion seems to be fair :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put those codes into the scripts array in your angular-cli.json if you are already importing it in your module.

Remove those lines from the scripts array in your angular-cli.json and you are probably good to go.

Also, you probably don't need to use full paths in your import, you could use this

```
import { Ng2SliderComponent } from 'ng2-slider-component';
import { SlideAbleDirective } from 'ng2-slideable-directive';
import { Ng2StyledDirective } from 'ng2-styled-directive';
```

Comment: There is no problem with your code, the problem is with the Ng2SliderComponent, you should consider using another component, maybe Angular's Material one: https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview

Comment: .Ng2SliderComponent.html:28 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of undefined at Ng2StyledDirective .this error solutions

Comment: Seriously, the last version of this component is 1 year old, it's not maintained, you should really consider using another one, you are trying to fix errors that are not yours, you shouldn't waste so much time on this kind of thing.